# Padding not working within pre block even with a wrapper div?

Tags: html, css, web

html code:

```
<div class="prewrap">
<pre>
stepsize = .01
samplestimes = 30
universex = seq(-1, 1, stepsize)
universey = sin(pi * universex)
</pre>
</div>
```

css code:

```
#prewrap {
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
    padding: 26px;
}
pre {
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tc7mD/

Using latest firefox and chrome on kubuntu 13.10

Comment: Looks fine to me. How is it not working?

Comment: appears to be working just fine? What is the problem?

Comment: What browser are you using, it's fine on the latest Firefox.

Comment: Sorry, wrong jsfiddle link, now updated.

Comment: Are you Kidding? changing question and your own solution(s) is fun :)

Answer (score 1):

Your selectors do not match.

CSS `.xx {}` for use with HTML `class="xx"`

CSS `#xx {}` for use with HTML `id="xx"`.

You need the period (to indicate class, rather than ID).

```
.prewrap {
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
    padding: 26px;
}
pre {
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tc7mD/1/

Comment: Oh, my stupid mistake. Haven't used css much. Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes just takes another pair of eyes ;) Welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You're using `#prewrap` to try to style a`<div>` with a `class` of `prewrap`. Try using `.prewrap` instead.